# Select word instead of row on double click on text

Tags: windows, text-editing, selection, text-cursor

When I double click a word in any browser or text editor, the whole line gets selected for some reason. However, I want only the underlying word to be selected (whether including trailing spaces or not doesn't really matter). What windows settings should I change?

(I am using windows 10, and haven't noticed such behaviour before. The setting has to be OS-related, as I notice this behaviour in all applications.)

Comment: Not a windows expert but selecting the whole line/paragraph  is sometimes obtained with a triple-click. And if your double-clicks end up as triple-clicks it may be a mouse problem (aging contacts, low battery...).

Comment: @xenoid You were right, it was a problem with the touch pad. It works slightly differently than the previous ones. You may post it as an answer...

Comment: OK, answer added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a windows expert but selecting the whole line/paragraph is sometimes obtained with a triple-click. And if your double-clicks end up as triple-clicks it may be a mouse problem (aging contacts, low battery...).